# Error on adding StreamReader instance

Tags: c#, text-files, streamreader

```
 private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string txt = "";
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
            ofd.FileName = "File";
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName));

                while (txt != null) {



                    txt += sr.ReadLine() + "\n";
                    if (txt != null) richTextBox1.Text += txt;
                    else sr.Dispose();

                }

            }

        }
```

This is my code which is intended to run when the Menu Strip item open is clicked. But somehow this create a stuck on my application. What is the error in code?

Comment: Is this an Windows Application? have you tried setting a breakpoing to see where it might get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending to txt so it never can be null try

```
   string line;
   while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
      txt += line + "\n";
      if (txt != null) richTextBox1.Text += txt;
      else sr.Dispose(); // Remove after seeing below
   }
```

Also, you should **always** dispose your streamreader so wrap your while loop like so (replace streamreader line too)

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName)))
{
//While loop here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate error in your code is in the loop condition:

```
  while (txt != null)
```

Since txt is not null, your application stucks in infinite loop.
There're some other issues:

1. You should always dispose IDisposable (StreamReader in your code)
2. Do not add to string, use StringBuilder

So, if you want to read file line by line into RichEdit you can do it
like that

```
  OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
  ofd.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
  ofd.FileName = "File";

  StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();

  if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName))) {
      while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        if (Sb.Length > 0) {
          Sb.AppendLine();
          Sb.Append(sr.ReadLine());
        }
        else
          Sb.Append(sr.ReadLine());
    }

    richTextBox1.Text += Sb.ToString();
  }
```